# I need to know when firebase observation done completely

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to observe multiple data at once using firebase, the observation block keeps looping until it fetchs all the data. I need to know when it is actually done so I can execute another block. How can I do that?

```
databaseRef.child("First_Secondary_Grade").child("0").child("0").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
        (snapshot) in

        if let dictoinary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let dataofthequsation = structofthedata()

            dataofthequsation.setValuesForKeys(dictoinary)

            }

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think i figured it out

```
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var gotitall = 0
```

// First you need to observe single event to get the real count of children  in swift 3 observe will count the keys inside a child. That's why!

```
   databaseRef.child("First_Secondary_Grade").child("0").child("0").observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with:{ (snap) in
        gotitall = Int(snap.childrenCount)
        databaseRef.child("First_Secondary_Grade").child("0").child("0").observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in
            if let dictoinary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                let dataofthequsation = structofthedata()

                dataofthequsation.setValuesForKeys(dictoinary)
                self.dataofthequsation.append(dataofthequsation)

// this is will run when the block runs through all children

                if gotitall == self.dataofthequsation.count {
                    completion()
                }
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: If you tested and it works, you can accept your own answer.